# Drupal 9 - form in custom module using Controller - html tag form not present

Tags: forms, drupal, twig, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I'm trying to render limited user edit form on custom page using Drupal Controller.
In the routing.yml I defined _controller, I do not want to use _form.

I want to display on the form e.g. only timezone field, but not the rest. And I'm not able to achieve it. I can render this field, other fields like form_build_id, form_id, form_token
But form html tag is not rendered at all.
It works only if I display in twig whole form like this {{ form.form }}

Here are my files:

my_module.info.yml

```
name: 'My module'
type: module
description: 'my module'
core_version_requirement: ^8.8 || ^9
```

my_module.routing.yml

```
my_module.mymodule_controller_view::
  path: '/my-module'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MymoduleController::view'
    _title: 'My module'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

my_module.module

```
<?php

function my_module_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{
    $templates = array(
        'my_module_form' => [
            'render element' => 'form',
        ],
    );

    return $templates;
}
```

MymoduleController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

class MymoduleController extends ControllerBase
{

    public function view()
    {
        $data['header'] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<h1>HEADER</h1>',
        ];

        $user = User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
        $formObject = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
            ->getFormObject('user', 'default')
            ->setEntity($user);

        $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($formObject);

        $data['form'] = [
            '#theme' => 'my_module_form',
            'form' => $form,
        ];

        $data['footer'] = [
            '#type' => 'markup',
            '#markup' => '<h3>footer</h3>',
        ];

        return $data;

    }

}
```

my-module-form.html.twig

```
<div>TWIG TEMPLATE</div>

{{ form.form.timezone }}
{{ form.form.form_build_id }}
{{ form.form.form_token }}
{{ form.form.form_id }}
{{ form.form.actions }}
```

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Since this is drupal related question please consider moving it to https://drupal.stackexchange.com which is dedicated exchange site for those questions. It is more likely to receive better answers there and contribute to the Drupal community.

Comment: OK, thanks. Created on drupal.stackexchange.com https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295479/drupal-9-form-in-custom-module-using-controller-html-tag-form-not-present-in